# Best way to quantify if a curve is similar to another while shiftting them along x-axis

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

I have two curves represented by arrays `a` and `b` of the same size `N`.

I want to know if they are the same curve just shifted along x-axis.

In order to quantify this similarity, my first idea was to compute the euclidean distance point to point and sum them all. Then shift the array so next iteration I compare `a(x)` with `b(x+k)`. And proceed with the iteration looking for a point where the sum of euclidean distances is the smaller.

If I find the `k` where the sum of the distances is smaller I can say that `a` and `b` are closest when I shift `b` by `k`.

The problem is, whenever I do a shift I start excluding points so distances are not the amount of distances compared are not the same between each iteration. So I need to use a subset of N and do fewer shifts.

What is the best way to find this? I remember something similar in University using convolution but I don't know if I am on the right track.

For context I am using python and numpy to compute this.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The signal-processing tag suggests these data represent _periodic_ functions. If that's right, the shift operation should be done "mod $N$," namely comparing `a(x)` and `b((x+k)%N)` (assuming that's the right python syntax for taking the remainder on division by $N$). In other words, any values shifted off the front of the list get tacked on to the end of the list.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks for replying. I found the RMSD to be a good solution for this measure. Although for finer grain I will do some linear interpolation instead of the array shifting.